# How do I resolve a none type error within a package (ecco_v4_py)

Tags: python, spyder

I recently had to recreate an environment after updating to Mac OS Big Sur and running into a common issue with Spyder not opening. A key component of that environment is the ecco_v4_py package necessary for processing ECCO state estimate data.

I managed to get the package installed into the environment, but whenever I try to load it in with `import ecco_v4_py as ecco` I get the following error.

```
 File "/Users/drew/anaconda3/envs/Salt/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 632, in cleandoc
    lines = doc.expandtabs().split('\n')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'expandtabs'
```

I have tried creating a fresh environment with just ecco_v4_py and Spyder, but that gives the same error. I have also tried creating a fresh environment with a downgraded version of the package, but that also causes this error.

Looking more deeply into the issue, I go to the line in the library code that is throwing the error.

```
def cleandoc(doc):
    """Clean up indentation from docstrings.

    Any whitespace that can be uniformly removed from the second line
    onwards is removed."""
    try:
        lines = doc.expandtabs().split('\n') #This is the line that is failing
    except UnicodeError:
        return None
    else:
        # Find minimum indentation of any non-blank lines after first line.
        margin = sys.maxsize
        for line in lines[1:]:
            content = len(line.lstrip())
            if content:
                indent = len(line) - content
                margin = min(margin, indent)
        # Remove indentation.
        if lines:
            lines[0] = lines[0].lstrip()
        if margin < sys.maxsize:
            for i in range(1, len(lines)): lines[i] = lines[i][margin:]
        # Remove any trailing or leading blank lines.
        while lines and not lines[-1]:
            lines.pop()
        while lines and not lines[0]:
            lines.pop(0)
        return '\n'.join(lines)
```

But when I run just this block it works, so I'm not sure why it throws an error when I try to import the package.

Small edit: I've also tried installing an earlier version of python, but this does not solve the problem. I tried editing the file that was throwing the error to fix the problem, but further errors appear down the line.

Additional edit: I managed to get the ecco_v4_py package to work appropriately by manually going in and editing files as errors showed up. For me it required changing `except UnicodeError` to `except (UnicodeError, AttributeError)`. For the remaining errors I needed to force certain variables to be interpreted as strings using the `str()` command. I'm still not sure if there will be unforeseen consequences of taking this brute-force approach, so I haven't marked this as the answer.